# Google Analytics : Custom Campaign using old Tracking Profile

Tags: google-analytics

From the reference link, I know that links can be better tracked with Custom Campaign attributes. However, I don't find the options in old Google Analytics profile. How can I enable the feature in old Tracking Profile? or can I upgrade the old tracking profile to new Universal Tracking?

Reference: [Custom Campaigns in Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***How can I enable the feature in old Tracking Profile? or can I upgrade the old tracking profile to new Universal Tracking?***

There's no need to upgrade to [Universal Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en&ref_topic=2790009) for tracking [Custom Campaigns](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863), which would require a new property and *analytics.js* tracking code if you did - as covered [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2817075?hl=en).

You can view Campaigns in the Traffic Sources section of the Google Analytics reporting interface, as covered [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCampaigns).

Use the [URL builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en&topic=1007028) to add Custom Campaign parameters to your URLs, and add Custom Campaign Tracking `ga.js` methods covered [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCampaigns#customCampaignTracking). Using [_setCampNameKey](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCampNameKey) for example defines the name of your campaign so that it will appear in the list of Campaigns in the Traffic Sources report.